# How to open web brower by using AWS post lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda

I have written the piece of code below:

```
static async postSearchResult(httpContext: HttpContext, injector: Injector) {
    const log = injector.get(Log);
    const service = injector.get(Service);
    try {
        let result = await service.redirectToUI(JSON.parse(httpContext.getRequestBody()));

        httpContext.ok(result, 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    } catch (e) {
        httpContext.fail(e, 500);
    }
}

protected redirectToUI(response: any) {
    // If any post api call happened then it should open web browser and pass some field as query parameter
    window.open("https://www.google.com?abc=response.abc");
    return response ? response : "failed";
}
```

Here I am getting the following error :

> Execution failed ReferenceError: Window is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Improved wording and

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish doesn't make much of a sense. Lambda is a back-end service. To open new browser window, you need to use front-end JavaScript, not  back-end Node (on the back-end, you have no access to the front-end `window` object).

If you want to open a new browser window as a reaction to some back-end response, then you can send some indicator in the HTTP response (i.e `shouldOpenNewWindow: true` as a part of the response object), parse that response on the front-end and it the indicator is present, then you can issue `window.open` command. But it has to be done on front-end.